# How do I create 4 different lists of random numbers without overlapping them using Python?

Tags: python, list, random, numbers

I need to create 4 lists of random numbers containing 6 numbers each, these numbers can't overlap. How can I do it? The below only generates 1 list. I need 4.

```
import random

list_numbers = [random.randint(8,29) for x in range(6)]
print(list_numbers)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "overlap"? If you mean the same number can't appear twice in a list, use `random.sample(range(8, 28), k=6)`. If you mean that if a number appears in one list, it can't appear in another (i.e. all lists must have unique elements), use `random.shuffle(list)` and then split the result into 4 lists of 6 elements each.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `random.sample(range(8, 28+1), k=6)`

Comment: @Boris the range from 8 to 28 only contains 20 numbers, you'd need to have 24 to get 4 unique lists of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Luciana, you need to clarify what you mean "can't overlap".
Be aware that the randint() function you are calling does not guarantee uniqueness within the set.
I just ran your program three times and the third time yielded: [14, 9, 22, 8, 17, 9].
So don't the two 9's constitute 'overlap'?

Anyway, if you just want four lists of six random integers you can call the function four times. Or call it once with range(24) and sub-divide the lists.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using NumPy instead.

```
import numpy as np

gen_list = np.random.choice(range(4,29), 24, replace = False).reshape(-1,4)
```